# ASP.NET Razor Model syntax in the view

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

a few newbie questions here:

In a strongly typed view, why:

```
@model MyProj.Models.User
```

Why do we use lambdas: ? What exactly does that do? Why not just model.Email?

```
1. @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Email)
```

Why doesn't this work? Didn't we call the variable model? (I know I should use @html.() but why isn't model recognisable?

```
2. users name is: @model.Name
```

Why does it work with an uppercase 'M'? Didnt we name it with a lower case?

```
3. users name is: Model.Name
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Why do we use lambdas: ? What exactly does that do? Why not just
>   model.Email?

The [DisplayNameFor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh833706%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) as well as all the other [*For helper methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd493063%28v=vs.108%29) are taking advantage of the ability of lambda expressions to participate in [Expression Trees](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx).

By itself this lambda expression is simply taking in a model type and returning a String. But there is more information needed to get the display name.

In pseudo code, that method is doing:

1.) Treat the lambda as an [Expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb335710%28v=vs.108%29.aspx)
2.) Parse the expression to get the name of the property
3.) Use reflection to get the [DisplayNameAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.displaynameattribute.aspx) for that property
4.) Extract the value if it exists, otherwise use the name of the property
5.) Generate a label for that property using either the display name, or property name

Without using Expression trees, you would end up having to pass the property name in as a string... and that just sucks. This provides a strongly typed way of using reflection without [magic strings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_string).

> Why doesn't this work? Didn't we call the variable model? (I know I
>   should use @html.() but why isn't model recognisable?

`@model` is a [special directive](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/10/19/asp-net-mvc-3-new-model-directive-support-in-razor.aspx) that is treated differently by Razor. It's like a reserved keyword that isn't any different than `class` or `int`.

> Why does it work with an uppercase 'M'? Didnt we name it with a lower
>   case?

`Model` is a property on your view that has the type you defined using the `@model` directive, and references your model. Without using the `@model` directive it would have a type of `dynamic`.